# Select from a sub select using the same table optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

how would you optimize this query which currently takes 10s? I need to select ids with the all enties that are filtered inside a subquery with specific conditions.

```
select temp.ip, vas_updates.setting, vas_updates.version
from (select count(id_update) as counter, ip
      from vas_updates
      where date(date)="2016-05-09" and
            time(date) between("14:00:00")  and ("23:00:00")
      group by ip
      having counter =2
     ) temp, vas_updates
 where vas_updates.ip = temp.ip
 order by ip;
```

I bet it takes so much time because the query has `from temp, vas_updates`, is there a way to isolate the "last query"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
select i.ip, u.setting, u.version
from (select count(id_update) as counter, ip
      from vas_updates
      where date between '2016-05-09 14:00:00' and '2016-05-09 23:00:00'
      group by ip
      having counter = 2
     ) i join
     vas_updates u
     on u.ip = i.ip
 order by ip;
```

Then index on `vas_updates(date, ip)` and `vas_updates(ip)` should help.

Comment: The index on ip basically fixed the problem, also great method.